# How do I configure NestJS to run mongosh scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, nestjs, mongo-shell

I have the need to dynamically create mongo databases when a new user is registered on a SaaS platform.

How do I configure NestJS to run the scripts needed, **to create the database**, as well as how to *dynamically connect with database created for each user*?

And are there any better approaches to my usecase?

New User => Create New Database for them, and store details in the main SaaS database.

When user login, fetch DB details from main database, and create a connection to it, to read their data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kindly check the correct answer, I was able to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to make it thus.

I created a database service class, in it, I used the MongooseModuleOptions to create a new connection, and injecting the Request Scope to it, I extracted the database name from the request and dynamically pass it to the uri in the createMongooseOptions method and that dynamically creates a connection.

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseOptionsFactory, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';


export class DatabaseService implements MongooseOptionsFactory{
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
    }

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
        const urii = process.env.CLUSTER+'/'+this.request.body.dbName+"?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
        return {
            uri: urii
        };
    }  
}
```

Then inside the users module, I insert data into a collection specified inside the schema, and that automatically uses the connection to create a database, collection and entry, if it exists, it uses the database and collection.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { InjectConnection, InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel:Model<UserDocument>){}
  
  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto)
    return createdUser.save()
  }

}
```

That worked perfectly for me.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to create a new db for each user. Why not craeting a users collection and than for each user create a new object. Mongo object can store quite a lot of information.

I'm not a pro in nestjs, but I don't think that there is a way to dynamically connect more db's. When you start your app a mongoDB instance is initiated, don't forget that all classes in nestjs are singletones.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Happens that I was able to work it out, I'll post the workaround shortly.